# Non-greedy Pattern Expression

Tags: regex, sed

I've been reading "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Friedl and trying to devise a common non-greedy pattern expression for a string that is delimited by a word.
Starting from basics where the delimited word is just a single character '**a**' the expression:

```
sed -r 's/([^a]*)(a)/\                                                                  
(1)\1(2)\2(ALL)&(END)/g' <<<"xaxxaxxxaxxx...aa..."

(1)x(2)a(ALL)xa(END)
(1)xx(2)a(ALL)xxa(END)
(1)xxx(2)a(ALL)xxxa(END)
(1)xxx...(2)a(ALL)xxx...a(END)
(1)(2)a(ALL)a(END)...
```

from which the pattern (with reference to Friedl) might be:

- [ ***normal* closing*** ]

Moving on to a real multi-character '**ab**' delimiter:

```
sed -r 's/([^a]*)((a[^b]*)*)(ab)/\                          
(1)\1(2)\2(3)\3(4)\4(ALL)&(END)/g' <<<"xabxxabxxxabxxx...abxxx...aabxxx...axxx...aaabxaabaxabaxaxabxaxaabxxaaabaaxxab..."

(1)x(2)(3)(4)ab(ALL)xab(END)
(1)xx(2)(3)(4)ab(ALL)xxab(END)
(1)xxx(2)(3)(4)ab(ALL)xxxab(END)
(1)xxx...(2)(3)(4)ab(ALL)xxx...ab(END)
(1)xxx...(2)a(3)a(4)ab(ALL)xxx...aab(END)
(1)xxx...(2)axxx...aa(3)axxx...aa(4)ab(ALL)xxx...axxx...aaab(END)
(1)x(2)a(3)a(4)ab(ALL)xaab(END)
(1)(2)ax(3)ax(4)ab(ALL)axab(END)
(1)(2)axax(3)axax(4)ab(ALL)axaxab(END)
(1)x(2)axa(3)axa(4)ab(ALL)xaxaab(END)
(1)xx(2)aa(3)aa(4)ab(ALL)xxaaab(END)
(1)(2)aaxx(3)aaxx(4)ab(ALL)aaxxab(END)...
```

from which the pattern might be:

- [ ***normal* (special*)* closing*** ]

For the subsequent '**abc**' delimiter the ***special*** expression can be extended to:

```
(a[^b]*)*(ab[^c]*)*
```

1. Is this correct?
2. Can it be proved?
3. Can the ***special*** expression be simplified?
4. Are there better/more efficient expressions for this? n.b. I'm not using perl's  non-greedy '*?' operator and avoiding alternation.
5. Where might I find reference material to this type of problem (Friedl alluded but stopped short of a published solution).

Comment: I'm so far off from "Mastering Regular Expressions" it's not even funny. I'm interrested however. Would you care to explain why you don't want to use those two operators: ? and |. Appreciate it.

Comment: Why not use negative lookahead ?

Comment: @Ikuty I'm afraid that's not part of sed's reportoire.

Comment: @potong You are right, I forgot to take the context into consideration.

Comment: @potong Good time to throw in a bounty. :)

Comment: Second example: what if input is `abacabc`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it looks correct.
2. You want to read about finite automata — nondeterministic (NFA) and deterministic (DFA). Simple regexp systems are essentially a handy notation for finite automata. Any good book on compilers will have a chapter covering NFA and DFA.
3. Probably not, or not much. The longer your word, the more backtracks you have to allow for.